# Mongo sort issues with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, sorting

When I try to sort a collection directly I can sort it on any fields without a problem like:

```
db.getCollection('collection_1').find({SOME_ID: 20246}).sort({SOME_STATUS: -1})
```

But when I am trying to sort the same collection in aggregate with other collection it does not sort on some of the fields. Like the above mentioned `SOME_STATUS` field does not sort anymore

```
db.getCollection('collection_1').aggregate([
                        { $match: { SOME_ID: 20246 } },
                        { $skip: 0 },
                        { $limit: 10 },
                        {$lookup: { from: 'collection_2', localField: 'SOME_OTHER_ID', foreignField: 'SOME_OTHER_ID', as: 'SOME_OTHER_INFO'}},
                        { $sort: { SOME_STATUS: 1} },
                        ])
```

This query has no effect on sorting.

What could probably be the catch here?

**UPDATE** : The problem was with sequence passed to the aggregate function, `$sort` should come before `$skip`. Writing it at last gives it only limited documents to sort from which or may not have the multiple values of `SOME_STATUS`

Comment: may be the documents are already sorted.

Comment: @Anit Khedekar: It's good to hear that you found the solution to your problem. Could you post it as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? Then you can [accept](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) your answer, which will take it off the unanswered list.

Comment: ok will do that. Thanks!